# How to list all the newly added files of a directory to a text file?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to list all the newly added files of a directory to a text file using below code
but the code is not working properly. Can anyone suggest a solution, or correct the code to meet my requirements? I am using the `type` command to delete last line of the Temp_File_List.txt file.

```
rem this batch script is used to list all the files created newly to a landing directory.
set LandingDir=C:\Documents and Settings\Shivam\Desktop\LandingDir\*.txt
set DateFile=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\DateFile.txt
set Temp_FileList=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\Temp_File_List.txt
set FileList=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\File_List.txt
set /P _PreviousDate=<%DateFile%

xcopy "%LandingDir%" /l /s /d:%_PreviousDate% .>%Temp_File_List%
type "%Temp_File_List%" | findstr /v File>%File_List%
echo %date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% >%DateFile%
```

Comment: Please can you edit your question so that your code is formatted as code? Doing so will make it easier to read.

Comment: Which part is it that is not working?

Comment: By the way, you are missing an underscore in your `set Temp_File_List = ...` statement. Everywhere else you refer to it with an underscore.

Comment: And the same with `set File_List = ...`

Comment: yah i have corrected those lines and inserted the underscore the script is working but not as expected.here it should list all the files which are added after the PreviousDate but not all.the script is listing all the files please suggest something to avert this

Comment: finally got it here is the script:

Comment: @Hal if you have fixed it yourself you can post your own solution as answer, there may be others looking for solution to same kind of problem.

Comment: how to paste it here am being restricted to edit or post my answer please suggest

Comment: @Hal I posted your solution as an answer. Feel free to accept it (by clicking the green checkmark outline next to it).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working script:

```
rem this batch script is used to list all the files hosted newly to a landing directory.
set LandingDir=C:\Documents and Settings\Shivam\Desktop\LandingDir\*.txt
set DateFile=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\DateFile.txt
set Temp_File_List=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\Temp_File_List.txt
set File_List=C:\Informatica\PowerCenter8.6.0\server\infa_shared\SrcFiles\File_List.txt
set /P _PreviousDate=<%DateFile%

xcopy "%LandingDir%" /l /s /d:%_PreviousDate% .>%Temp_File_List%
type "%Temp_File_List%" | findstr /v File>%File_List%
echo %date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4% >%DateFile%
```